# Make parts of body mesh go through clothing mesh during simulation?

Tags: animation, physics

I have a walk cycle set up on my model but when her hands pass her body they also affect the skirt she's wearing which messes the skirt physics up in ways that would be better if I just had her hands and lower arms pass through the mesh.

Is there any way to do that without separating and creating new arm and hand objects? I'd like to keep my model all as one object.

What I've done: delete all vertex groups attached to her fingers, hands, lower, and upper arms. Although this did help, it seems the skirt mesh still responds to her hands.

[image]

Edit: Pics of my cloth physics settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. What you gotta do is separate the mesh into parts that you want to keep as collision objects and those you don't. So, in my case, it was simply separating the lower arms from the rest of the body but still having them work together as part of the same armature. After that I removed the collision modifier and hid (H key) the lower arms which hides them from 3D view but not render view. So, the animation render looks the same but the arms pass through the skirt mesh the way I want.